# How to add image in crystal report header section dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

How to add image in crystal report header section dynamically?
I will doing on this code here

```
  PictureObject P = (PictureObject)doc.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["PicBoxHeader"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the file path and please follow the steps:

First, add a graphic as a placeholder into your report where you want it to display.

Then, right-click the graphic -> 'Format Graphic' -> 'Picture' tab -> Add a formula under 'Graphic Location' that builds your path string. Something like `'C:\Id Maker\' + {table.Clgid} + '.jpg'` should work.

For more, see these links: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mmzudQpRB_0

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-GAz7AH6-vA&itct=CA0QpDAYAiITCIXv-ZHG8s4CFWkZfwodtmgENTIHcmVsYXRlZEj9j8TS0M67tpoB&gl=US&client=mv-google&hl=en-GB